# A way to print rows in a alternate directions in Java without using 2D arrays..ArrayLists, LinkedLists

Tags: java, rows, alternate

for practice purposes, I'm trying to find a way to print rows of numbers in alternate for each row
 etc..

100  99  98  97  96 95 94 93 92 91
81   82  83  84  85 86 87 88 89 90
80 79 78 77 76 75 74 73......

....without the use of 2D arrays, ArrayLists, LinkedLists..

so far I've done it, but my solution to this is quite long and can be repetitive... was wondering if there's a 'shorter' way around this...

Here is what I've done...

```
public class PrintNumbers {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        PrintNumbers app = new PrintNumbers();
        app.display();
    }


    public void display()// main display
    {
        display_cell_left_to_right(100,90);
        display_cell_right_to_left(81,91);
        display_cell_left_to_right(80,70);
        display_cell_right_to_left(61,71);
        display_cell_left_to_right(60,50);
        display_cell_right_to_left(41,51);
        display_cell_left_to_right(40,30);
        display_cell_right_to_left(21,31);
        display_cell_left_to_right(20,10);
        display_cell_right_to_left(1,11);
        board_displayLine();


    }//end display method

    public void board_displayLine(){
        System.out.println("");
        for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--)
            System.out.print("+-------");

        System.out.print("+");
        System.out.println("");
    }//end board_displayLine

    //method to display cells from left to right according to a range of indexes
    public void display_cell_left_to_right(int max,int min){
        board_displayLine();
        for (int i = max; i > min; i--)//
            System.out.print("|"+i+"\t");
        System.out.print("|");
    }
    //same as above but vice versa
    public void display_cell_right_to_left(int min, int max){
        board_displayLine();
        for (int i = min; i < max; i++)
            System.out.print("|"+i+"\t");
        System.out.print("|");
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why without the use of 2D arrays, ArrayLists, LinkedLists?

Comment: Your solution would work just fine if you enclosed it in a loop, e.g. for (int start=100; start>0; start-=20) { display_cell_left_to_right(start, start-10); display_cell_right_to_left(start-19, start-9); }

Comment: well frankly..their code restrictions for my work..:\

Comment: Alright...got it...thanks Jerry :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
for(int i = 9; i>=0; i--){
    boolean right = (i%2 == 0);
    for(int j = (right?1:10); j!=0 && j!=11; j = j + (right?1:-1)){
        System.out.print(i*10 + j);
        System.out.print("\t");

    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: it works..but its the reversed of what i want...thanks.. btw 
what is this expression "right?1:10"

Comment: This is ternary operator. It is just short `IF THEN ELSE`. For more information look at wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operator

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version that's meant for humans:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int ROWS = 10;
    int MAX = 100;
    int currentValue = MAX;
    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < MAX / ROWS; j++) {
                System.out.print(currentValue-- + " ");
            }
        } else {
            currentValue -= MAX / ROWS;
            for (int j = MAX / ROWS; j >= 0; j--) {
                System.out.print((currentValue + ((MAX / ROWS) - j)) + " ");
            }
            currentValue--;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```